# How to stop time or print the time when a certain condition is met

Tags: python, python-3.7

This code is a simulation for a forest fire and I would like to get the simulation to stop when all the trees are 'charred' or alternatively to run to the end but print the time it took to burn all the trees. I'm not sure how to even start so help would be appreciated ! I do not have much experience with coding do the most simple method would be much appreciated because at the moment I am having to manually look at when all the trees are charred and it can be easy to miss the right time.

```
import pylab as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import scipy as sp
import random as rd
import copy as cp
import time as tm

cdict = {
  'red'  :  ( (0.0, 1.0, 1.0),
              (0.3, 0.0, 0.0),
              (0.6, 255./256, 255./256),
              (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)),

  'green':  ( (0.0, 1.0, 1.0),
              (0.3, 1.0, 1.0),
              (0.6, 160./256, 160./256),
              (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)),

  'blue' :  ( (0.0, 1.0, 1.0),
              (0.3, 0.0, 0.0),
              (0.6, 0.0, 0.0),
              (1.0, 0.0, 0.0))
        }
cm = mpl.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap('my_colormap', cdict, 1024)

empty, tree, fire, charred = range(4)

plt.ion()

fig1 = plt.figure(num=1)

fig1.clear()
plt.show()
fig1.canvas.draw()
fig1.canvas.flush_events()

def count_states(matrix_):

counts = [0,0,0,0]
w,h = sp.shape(matrix_)
for y in range(h):
    for x in range(w):
        state = matrix_[x,y]
        counts[int(state)] = counts[int(state)] + 1

return list(counts)

def visualise(figure,matrix,time):

plt.cla()

plt.pcolor(matrix.T, vmin=0, vmax=3, cmap=cm)

plt.axis('square')

plt.title('time = ' + str(time))

figure.canvas.draw()
figure.canvas.flush_events()
maxTime = 50
width = 20
height = 20
ptree = 1
initial_delay = 2
time_between_frames = 0.2
matrix = sp.zeros([width, height])

initial_forest = cp.copy(matrix)
for x in range(width):
for y in range(height):

    random = rd.random()

    if random < ptree:
        matrix[x,y] = tree
matrix[:0] = empty


newmatrix = cp.copy(matrix)

visualise(fig1,matrix,'initial')

plt.savefig(name + '_initial.png')


matrix[rd.randint(0,width-1), rd.randint(0,height-1)] = fire

tm.sleep(initial_delay)

for time in range(maxTime):

    visualise(fig1,matrix,time)


for y in range(height):

    for x in range(width):

        state = matrix[x,y]

        if state == fire:
            state = charred


        if state == tree:

            for dx in [-1,0,1]:

                for dy in [-1,0,1]:

                    if matrix[(x+dx)%width, (y+dy)%height] == fire:

                        state = fire
        newmatrix[x,y] = state
matrix, newmatrix = newmatrix, matrix
tm.sleep(time_between_frames)
visualise(fig1,matrix,maxTime)
plt.savefig(name + '_final.png')
```

Comment: `print(time.time())` when you want to know the current time (in unix time format). Or save the output of `time.time()` at the start, and subtract this from `time.time()` at the end to know seconds elapsed.

Comment: Or use logging and display time in the format of the log.